Is there a way to customise the sign in / register links that Firebase auth provides in a Flutter app?
I'm using the Firebase auth package to allow logins / sign-ins in my Flutter app. You can see the two screens attached: one is a SignInScreen() and the other is a RegisterScreen. However, on both apps, the link generated is "Sign in with phone". The links work as expected, it's just the text I want to change.
Or - if Firebase is treating phone registrations and phone sign-ups as the same thing, and I don't to handle things differently, is there a way to pick up after the SMS validation that the user is new?
Thanks!


Haven't tried anything to resolve this yet, as I can't find examples on how I could change this online.
import 'package:arcadious/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide PhoneAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SignInScreen(
            showAuthActionSwitch: false,
            providers: [
              PhoneAuthProvider(),
            ],
            subtitleBuilder: (context, action) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child:
                    Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                    child: const Text(
                      "SIGN IN TO ARCADIOUS",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 36,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Arcadious is the home of video games, old and new. Search a complete list of games, view media and build your collection. Play on your phone, legally, with added features such as achievements, multiplayer and controller support. Thank you for helping test the app!",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              );
            },
            footerBuilder: (context, action) {
              return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child:
                      Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(
                                40), // fromHeight use double.infinity as width and 40 is the height
                          ),
                          child: const Text(
                            'REGISTER A NEW ACCOUNT',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Outfit'),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => RegisterScreen(
                                        showAuthActionSwitch: false,
                                        providers: [
                                          PhoneAuthProvider(),
                                        ],
                                        subtitleBuilder: (context, action) {
                                          return Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 8.0),
                                            child: Column(
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            bottom: 20.0),
                                                    child: const Text(
                                                      "REGISTER FOR A NEW ARCADIOUS ACCOUNT",
                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.w700,
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontSize: 36,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  const Text(
                                                    "Arcadious is the home of video games, old and new. Search a complete list of games, view media and build your collection. Play on your phone, legally, with added features such as achievements, multiplayer and controller support. Tap the confusingly-worded 'Sign in with phone' below to get started!",
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ]),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        footerBuilder: (context, action) {
                                          return Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  top: 16),
                                              child: Column(
                                                  mainAxisSize:
                                                      MainAxisSize.max,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Container(
                                                      margin:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              bottom: 20.0),
                                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                                          style: ElevatedButton
                                                              .styleFrom(
                                                            minimumSize: const Size
                                                                .fromHeight(
                                                                40), // fromHeight use double.infinity as width and 40 is the height
                                                          ),
                                                          child: const Text(
                                                            'SIGN IN INSTEAD',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Outfit'),
                                                          ),
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                                          }),
                                                    ),
                                                    const Text(
                                                      'By registering a new account or by signing in, you agree to our Terms & Conditions, as well as our Privacy Policy.',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                                        fontSize: 12,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ]));
                                        },
                                      )),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'By registering a new account or by signing in, you agree to our Terms & Conditions, as well as our Privacy Policy.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]));
            },
          );
        }

        return const HomeScreen();
      },
    );
  }
}


Can you provide the code of the view? Btw, there's should be a button for the login in which you can change the text.

I've added the code as requested :).

I think that the "problem" is that you're using firebase function to create your login screen, so you have not the full control on what are you writing.
Instead of using the class SignInScreen, you should write your own page (if you want to customize everything).
You can use this code for making your buttong to signIn with google (so, call this function in the onTap() of the button, maybe showing some loading animation until you get a result from the future), and customize the page as you want
Future<dynamic> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await googleUser?.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
      );

      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('exception->$e');
    }
  }

